# request undefined with ajax call with laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to get response with ajax call but I get request undefined even I have Request classe and $request variable

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\student;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Course_category;
use Auth;
use App\User;

public function search_cat(Request $request) {
  $user= Auth::user();
  
  if ($request->ajax()) {
    $active_users=Course_category::with(['classe' => function($q) use($user) {
      $q->where('categorie_id', $request->search);
    }])->paginate(1);

    $output = "";

    if ($active_users) {
      // foreach($active_users as $user)
      // {
        return view('student.courses_search', compact('active_users'))->render();
      // }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you define your functions in this way? `public function getCourses(Request $request)`

Comment: @Arash yes i edit  the code

Comment: Did you import `Request` via `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your Controller? Also, you need to pass it forward to your closure via `use($user, $request)` (or just `use($request)` since you don't use `$user` in that `function($q)` block)

Comment: Try this `request()->ajax()` .

Comment: @Arash That's not the issue at all.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you it worked fine if you want you can write your answer in answers areas so i can accept it

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Sidenote, I can't write that as an answer, as this is simply a typo (you used `$user` instead of `$request`), so I have voted to close instead.

Comment: @TimLewis actualy i'm using user and request thank you

Comment: No worries; would simply still be `use ($user, $request)` instead of just `use ($user)`, which is still technically a typo. Sidenote, there's no harm in a closed question; this is still an acceptable question, just unlikely to help anyone else, and has been asked/answered before on the site.